# Performance of RedisClient.Get<T> C# with ServiceStack.Redis

Tags: c#, redis, json.net, servicestack

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public string Att1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime Att2 { get; set; }
    public KeyValuePair Att3 { get; set; }
    public Dictionary Att4 { get; set; }
}

var list = new List<MyEntity>(100);
//put to cache .....
var cached = RedisClient.Get<List<MyEntity>>(key) ; // take 9745.9745 ms
var raw = RedisClient.Get(key); //get raw of the same key just take < 10 ms
```

should i use Json.net for json serialization and use RedisClient.Get instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're likely getting hit by the first cache hit penalty. 
Take the first of each call of each API out of the timings.

The RedisClient uses the JsonSerializer underneath, which does exactly the same thing, pulls a string from Redis and calls JsonSerializer to deserialize the type.

Comment: what do you mead by the "first cache hit penalty"?

If i change to this order, the result is the same.
var raw = RedisClient.Get(key); //get raw of the same key just take < 10 ms
var cached = RedisClient.Get>(key) ; // take 9745.9745 ms

Comment: The first call takes longer than the rest because it needs to prep the delegate caches. If you're just getting a string you're doing less work in the 2nd call. 10s is an insane amount of time, for deserializing anything. You'll get faster results and smaller payloads using generics since you don't have to bind to late-bound object types.

Comment: I got the same each if i do this several times
 var cached = RedisClient.Get<List<MyEntity>>(key) ; // take 9745.9745 ms
var cached1 = RedisClient.Get<List<MyEntity>>(key) ; // take 9745.9745 ms

var cachedn = RedisClient.Get<List<MyEntity>>(key) ; // take 9745.9745 ms

Comment: I mean use Generic collections in your model as well, i.e. don't use .NET 1.0 object collections like `Dictionary` or `KeyValuePair` - use their generic equivalents instead.

Comment: The Type of Att3 & Att4 are:
System.Collections.Generic KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> and 
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>

Comment: Then there's something else going on that's not possible to tell from your example. Take Redis out of the equation (i.e. serialize and deserialse from JSON) to see if it's the JsonSerialzier or Redis. Then profile your code to find the bottleneck. And it matters what TKey/TValue is, they shouldn't be using objects either.

Comment: Thanks! I try to remove the  Att3 & Att4 from MyEntity, it get fast to just 15ms. But why? How can i do with Dictionary and KeyValuePair

Comment: No idea, I can't tell from that code sample - it's incomplete. But as a general rule avoid inheritance and object types in serializers - inspect the JSON output, if you're seeing **__type** then you're using late-bound types somewhere - they're inefficient.

Comment: Great thanks to @mythz ! Dictionary type is ok, it's caused by KeyValuePair. I'll try to found why KeyValuePair isn't friendly to JsonSerializer!